# Completing Deployment to Maven Central Repository

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-central

I'm working on deploying a github project to maven central repository.

Following the instructions outlined [here](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide), one of the contributors with write access to the github repository successfully issued the following:

```
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perform
```

However, the Nexus UI complained about not being able to find his GPG key and so we dropped the staged repository.

At this point we are trying to preform the release again. Since the github repository has already been correctly tagged, it would seem we only need to do the very last step:

```
mvn release:perform
```

It seemed that the right way to do this is by adding the `-DConnectionUrl` property, but there are no URLs for github tags/releases. Checking out the release locally and using the `-DlocalCheckout` does not either seem to work.

At this point, I'm thinking to do the remaining pieces manually.

How can I wrap this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

1. Created a file named `release.properties` under the project root directory and supplied the following key value pairs:

   `scm.url=`

   `scm.tag=`
2. Executed `mvn release:perform`